# GSA use connector for databases do not have metadata?

Tags: google-search-appliance

We are working on a GSA project. We are using GSA version 7.2 and Connector database adapter 3.2.4. 
That SQL as

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,
  FIRST_NAME,
  LAST_NAME,
  EMAIL,
  PHONE_NUMBER,
  HIRE_DATE,
  JOB_ID,
  SALARY,
  COMMISSION_PCT,
  MANAGER_ID,
  DEPARTMENT_ID
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES ;
```

How to write **"Stylesheet for Serving Results"** for show all metadata from SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must customize stylesheet as follow:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<xsl:for-each select="pland_connector"> <!-- name of connector -->
  <!-- now for every single field from the database you want to be able to filter upon or show in your result, add a meta-field -->
  <title><xsl:value-of select="LAST_NAME"/></title> <!-- don't forget the title -> that is the default title in the GSA result -->
  <meta name="EMPLOYEE_ID"><xsl:attribute name="content"><xsl:value-of select="EMPLOYEE_ID"/></xsl:attribute></meta> 
  <!-- mind the capital sensitivity of XML, dependend on the notation in you db view or table the value-of should be in capitals or not -->
  <meta name="LAST_NAME"><xsl:attribute name="content"><xsl:value-of select="LAST_NAME"/></xsl:attribute></meta>
  <meta name="FIRST_NAME"><xsl:attribute name="content"><xsl:value-of select="FIRST_NAME"/></xsl:attribute></meta>
  <meta name="EMAIL"><xsl:attribute name="content"><xsl:value-of select="EMAIL"/></xsl:attribute></meta>
  <meta name="PHONE_NUMBER"><xsl:attribute name="content"><xsl:value-of select="PHONE_NUMBER"/></xsl:attribute></meta>
  <!-- Etc..... -->

</xsl:for-each>
<!-- You can add static metadata to -->
<meta name="test" content="Person"/>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Just see what data you want in the content-field -->
<xsl:for-each select="pland_connector"> <!-- Name of database -->
  <h1><xsl:value-of select="NAME"/></h1></br>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`
```

I think you will completed.